# SQL Code how to get data for a current year and month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure how to select the month of September

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(QtyOrdered * Price as money)) 'Total Order Price for September'
FROM tblPurchaseOrderLine
WHERE year (DateNeeded) = year (GETDATE())
```

Comment: Sql is a standard, On which database you work?

Comment: For SQL query questions you should always provide a [mcve] including your schema and sample data.

Comment: @FoxCy SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

Try the below sample query to get the data for current year and month.

```
SELECT * from <tablename>
WHERE year = YEAR(GETDATE())
and month = MONTH(GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

add this predicate end of where

```
AND month (DateNeeded)  =9
```

Comment: THANKS! SELECT 

SUM(CAST(QtyOrdered * Price as money))
  'Total Order Price for September'
FROM tblPurchaseOrderLine
WHERE year (DateNeeded) =
   year (GETDATE())
and month(DateNeeded) = 9
;
I tried this

Answer (score 0):

add this to the end

```
AND month (DateNeeded)  = 9
```